# What is the npm command to install .circleci/config.yml for cypress test

Tags: cypress, circleci

We are having CircleCI CI/CD pipeline for our project. I would need to setup cypress test to run on CircleCi pipeline. Could anyone please advise about the `npm install` command to create `circle.yml` or `.circleci/config.yml file` under the root folder:

[image]

Comment: You don't use a `npm` command to create a CircleCI YAML config - that is written manually and added to the repo manually.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of my `circle.yml`, which is located in my project root:

```
version: 2.1
jobs:
  test:
    docker:
    - image: cypress/base:10
    steps:
    - checkout
    - restore_cache:
        keys:
        - cache-{{ arch }}-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
    - run:
        name: Yarn install
        command: yarn install --frozen-lockfile
    - save_cache:
        key: cache-{{ arch }}-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
        paths:
        - ~/.cache
    - run:
        command: yarn lint
    - run:
        command: yarn test
    - run:
        command: yarn test-e2e
    - run:
        command: yarn run semantic-release
workflows:
  build:
    jobs:
    - test
  version: 2
```

You can replace `yarn test-e2e` with your cypress cli command, for example `npm run cypress:run`